# How to do a modular arithmetic with negative exponents?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was reading a solution which writes:so we need to compute $2^{-11} \pmod{25}$. But this is simply, by Fermat's Little Theorem, $2^9 = 512 \equiv 12 \pmod{25}$.

However I don't really understand the process here: how should I apply the theorem to get this? Thanks in advance

Comment: So you need $\;2^{-11}\pod{25}\;$ ?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the mod25 after..

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem does not apply, since the modulus (25) is not a prime number. They probably meant to say Euler's Theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author actually uses Euler's stronger version of Fermat's little theorem: $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. In this case $2^{\phi(25)}\equiv2^{20}\equiv1 \pmod{25}$. So $2^{-11}\equiv2^{-11}2^{20}\equiv2^9\equiv12 \pmod{25}$.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful about what the negative in the exponent means, namely $2^{-1}$ is the element $a$ that satisfies 
$$
2a\cong 1\mod 25
$$
With a little thought, this is seen to be $a=13$. Then 
$$
2^{-11}=13^{11}
$$
which you may compute by finding a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

*IF* (and it is a *big* if) $\gcd (a,n) = 1$ then we know that there a power $k$ ($\phi(n)$ is one such possible $k$) so that $a^k \equiv 1 \mod n$ and that and the $a^j$ form a group under multiplication modulo $n$.  And further that $a^{j+k}\equiv a^j \mod 25$.

[It does NOT follow that $k = \phi(n)$ is the *smallest* such power, nor that the order of the group is $\phi(n)$. But it does follow that smallest such power will divide $\phi(n)$]

So as $\gcd(2,25)=1$ then we know, among several other things, 1) $2^{\pi(25)} = 2^{20} \equiv 1 \mod 25$[$*$] and that 2) That if is a unique $a$ so that $2a \equiv 1 \mod 25$ and for notation purposes we may notate $a$ as $2^{-1}$ and that 3) for $2^j$ that $2^j*2^{20-j} = 2^20 \equiv 1 \mod 25$ and for notation purposes we may notate $2^{20 - j}$ as $2^{-j}$ and $2^j*2^{-j} \equiv 1 \mod 25$.

So what is the value of $2^{-11}$?  Well $2^{-11} \equiv 2^{-11}*1\equiv 2^{-11}*2^{20} \equiv 2^9\mod 25$.

[$*$] as it turns out $20$ is the smallest such power so that $2^k \equiv 1 \mod 25$ but we can not tell that without testing that $2^{10} \equiv -1 \not \equiv 1 \mod 15$ or that $2^4 \equiv 16\mod 25$.  But we do not need to know that $20$ is the smallest such power.  Just that $2^{20} \equiv 1 \mod 25$.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

$$2^{-1}=13\pmod{25}\;,\;\;\text{because}\;\;2\cdot13=1\pmod{25}$$

It's **exactly the same (when possible)** as with real ("usual") numbers. For example, $\;7^{-1}=\frac17\;$ because $\;7\cdot\frac17=1\;$ .

Thus, you actually want to solve

$$2^{-11}=\left(2^{-1}\right)^{11}=13^{11}\pmod{25}$$

...and now you can do as usual.